# Align items with flexbox css

Tags: css, flexbox

I need to align the red divs in the same position with different labels that can occupy several lines or one, but leave the space of the blue div if the next or previous column contains it.

how can i do that?

https://codepen.io/aldozumaran/pen/zbWLpb

```css
.main-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.main-flex .item-flex {
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 1 45%;
}
.main-flex .item-flex label {
  flex: 1;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
.main-flex .item-flex .input-flex {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f00;
}
.main-flex .item-flex .input-flex-2 {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-flex ">
  <div class="item-flex bg-white">
    <label for="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A aliquid animi aperiam atque consequatur corporis dolor eius </label>
    <div class="input-flex"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-flex  bg-white">
    <label for="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A aliquid animi aperiam atque consequatur corporis dolor eius </label>
    <div class="input-flex"></div>
    <div class="input-flex-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-flex bg-white">
    <label for="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A aliquid animi aperiam atque consequatur corporis dolor eius Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, animi cum fuga fugit iusto laudantium libero minus molestias obcaecati officiis omnis quam quidem quod sit ut. At quasi rem vitae? </label>
    <div class="input-flex"></div>
    <div class="input-flex-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-flex bg-white">
    <label for=""> At quasi rem vitae? </label>
    <div class="input-flex"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-flex bg-white">
    <label for=""> At quasi rem vitae? </label>
    <div class="input-flex"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-flex bg-white">
    <label for=""> At quasi rem vitae? </label>
    <div class="input-flex"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what's the output you expect

Answer (score 0):

Do the red divs have to be flexible/responsive?

One way to do it is to leave the divs there, but just remove the color:

```
<div class="main-flex ">
   <div class="item-flex bg-white">
       <label for="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A aliquid animi aperiam atque consequatur corporis dolor eius </label>
       <div class="input-flex"></div>
       <div class="input-flex-2" style="background: none"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="item-flex  bg-white">
       <label for="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A aliquid animi aperiam atque consequatur corporis dolor eius </label>
       <div class="input-flex"></div>
       <div class="input-flex-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-flex bg-white">
       <label for="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A aliquid animi aperiam atque consequatur corporis dolor eius Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, animi cum fuga fugit iusto laudantium libero minus molestias obcaecati officiis omnis quam quidem quod sit ut. At quasi rem vitae? </label>
       <div class="input-flex"></div>
       <div class="input-flex-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-flex bg-white">
       <label for=""> At quasi rem vitae? </label>
       <div class="input-flex"></div>
       <div class="input-flex-2" style="background: none"></div>
  </div>
```

The CSS didn't change.

Comment: item-flex are responsive, on small devices are 100% width 1 in a row, or in large devices 3 in an row

Answer (score 0):

You can consider a bottom margin on the red that you rectify with a negative margin on the blue div

```css
.main-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.main-flex .item-flex {
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 1 45%;
}
.main-flex .item-flex label {
  flex: 1;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
.main-flex .item-flex .input-flex {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f00;
  margin-bottom:40px;
}
.main-flex .item-flex .input-flex-2 {
  margin-top:-40px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-flex ">
  <div class="item-flex bg-white">
    <label for="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A aliquid animi aperiam atque consequatur corporis dolor eius </label>
    <div class="input-flex"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-flex  bg-white">
    <label for="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A aliquid animi aperiam atque consequatur corporis dolor eius </label>
    <div class="input-flex"></div>
    <div class="input-flex-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-flex bg-white">
    <label for="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A aliquid animi aperiam atque consequatur corporis dolor eius Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, animi cum fuga fugit iusto laudantium libero minus molestias obcaecati officiis omnis quam quidem quod sit ut. At quasi rem vitae? </label>
    <div class="input-flex"></div>
    <div class="input-flex-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-flex bg-white">
    <label for=""> At quasi rem vitae? </label>
    <div class="input-flex"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-flex bg-white">
    <label for=""> At quasi rem vitae? </label>
    <div class="input-flex"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-flex bg-white">
    <label for=""> At quasi rem vitae? </label>
    <div class="input-flex"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```